# why object margin is applied based on absolute parent and not direct relative parent

Tags: html, css

A bit hard to title =>

I have the following code

==> PROBLEM <==
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WVpEGQ?editors=1100

==> OK <==
https://codepen.io/crocsx-the-styleful/pen/EqWvRR

Basically, I would like that margin/padding etc on element contained in `subcontent-header` to apply RELATIVELY to the `subcontent-header` div
this div has a position:relative, but it applied outside of the div and it pushed my `subcontent-header` down instead

```css
/* -- MAIN -- */
    body, html {
        background: @body-background-color url(/assets/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0;
        background-size: contain;
        color:@body-color;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Arial','Hiragino Sans','ヒラギノ角ゴシック',YuGothic,'Yu Gothic','メイリオ', Meiryo,'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック','MS PGothic';
        // font-family: @font-name !important;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
       overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .header {
        position: relative;
        background:green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
    }
    
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: calc(100% - 60px) !important;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      background: red;
    }
    
    .footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        background: blue;
    }
    
    .subcontent{
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background:rgba(155,155,155,0.5)
    }
    
    .subcontent-header{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30%;
      background:rgba(155,0,0,0.5)
    }
    
    .subcontent-content{
       position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background:rgba(0,0,155,0.5) 
    }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="subcontent">
        <div class="subcontent-header">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent-content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain further about what you are trying to achieve? It's a little confusing.

Comment: I dont know how to explain more. My title is an h1 with a margin. in the snippet, you will see above the title a beige part. this beige strip is actually the margin of the h1 that is pushing  instead of just the h1, the entire div containing my h1. What I would like is, the margin of the h1 is applied to the h1 INSIDE the red div, and the red div is connected to the green div without any beige part .

Here is an h1, but in the app, any container div with padding or margin is always applied relatively to the div with position absolute, but not on the element relatively to the parent.

Comment: I get it now. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you didn't set your `h1`'s position to absolute.

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.subcontent-header h1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Sample working code below

```css
/* -- MAIN -- */
    body, html {
        background: @body-background-color url(/assets/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0;
        background-size: contain;
        color:@body-color;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Arial','Hiragino Sans','ヒラギノ角ゴシック',YuGothic,'Yu Gothic','メイリオ', Meiryo,'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック','MS PGothic';
        // font-family: @font-name !important;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
       overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .header {
        position: relative;
        background:green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
    }
    
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: calc(100% - 60px) !important;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      background: red;
    }
    
    .footer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        background: blue;
    }
    
    .subcontent{
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background:rgba(155,155,155,0.5)
    }
    
    .subcontent-header{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30%;
      background:rgba(155,0,0,0.5)
    }
    
    .subcontent-header h1 {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .subcontent-content{
       position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background:rgba(0,0,155,0.5) 
    }
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="subcontent">
        <div class="subcontent-header">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent-content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
 </div>
```

Comment: that's a bit confusing. If container1 is absolute, but container2 is relative.

if I put container2 inside container1 and then something inside container2 it should be positionned relatively to container2 not container1.

is there an explanation ?

Comment: @Bobby any `position: absolute` elements will position relative to closest parent element with `position: relative`. The reason why your `h1` didn't position relative to your container2 is because you didn't style it with `position: absolute`. By adding `position: absolute` to your `h1`, it will now be relative to your container2 which will solve your problem. If my solution above worked, please mark it as the answer so others with same problem will know. thanks